# Zend Lucene - cannot search numbers

Tags: zend-framework, lucene, zend-search-lucene

Using Zend Lucene I cannot search numbers in description fields

Added it like this:

```
$doc->addField(Zend_Search_Lucene_Field::Text('description', $current_item['item_short_description'], 'utf-8'));
```

Googling for this showed that applying following code should solve the problem, but it did not..:

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive());
```

any thougts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to set the default analyzer **twice**: On the indexing process as well as on the searching process.

Use the code line from above:

```
Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer::setDefault(new Zend_Search_Lucene_Analysis_Analyzer_Common_TextNum_CaseInsensitive());
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you use that command before or after calling Zend_Search_Lucene::open()?

Calling it beforehand definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about 'zend', but for deal with number in lucene, you need use following technique:

- To place int to document use following:

  document.Add(new Field(FIELD_SPEC, NumberTools.LongToString(YOUR_INT), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
- To locate value use Term: Term(FIELD_SPEC, NumberTools.LongToString(YOUR_INT))

Comment: How do I use it for description? I want so that numbers inside description are searchable. I don't just have a "seprate integer".

Comment: @Pavel Dubinin - look at my note: "To locate value use Term:..." So when you need search you create this as part of BooleanQuery where Term is constructed using NumberTools. Little bit complicated if you use standard qury parser - in this case make preprocess by replacing all numbers in queries by value rendered NumberTools